# Bubble line Up/Down in any modes

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

The arrow keys can easily be enhanced and I would like to add the "bubble" feature for all modes.

The idea is to use the `<C-Up/Down>` to take the line and move it along the text and preserve the cursor position. If possible I also would like the `cut` with `dd` to not alter the yank registers.

The following works great in normal and visual mode, but not in insertion where  I obviously need some help:

```
nmap <C-Up> ddkP
nmap <C-Down> ddp
imap <C-Up>   <C-C>:call BubbleUp()<cr>
imap <C-Down> <C-C>:call BubbleDown()<cr>
vmap <C-Up> xkP`[V`]
vmap <C-Down> xp`[V`]

function! BubbleUp()
        let l:col = virtcol('.') + 2
        normal! ddkP
        execute 'normal! '.l:col.'|i'
endfunction

function! BubbleDown()
        let l:col = virtcol('.') + 2
        normal! ddp
        execute 'normal! '.l:col.'|i'
endfunction
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? If I try it, it seems to work? Also see [Faster way to move a block of text](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/598/51) btw.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `<C-o>` instead of `<C-c>` for your imap

Comment: I had problems in reproducing this (although finally managed) because there is no terminfo entry for `<C-arrow>` and my terminal was pretty wacky about them.  [This answer helped](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/how-to-fix-ctrl-arrows-in-vim), this may or may not be related to your issue.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trick I picked up a long time ago:

```
nnoremap <silent> <M-c>  @='"zyy"zp'<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <M-c>  @='"zy"zPgv'<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <M-j>  @='"zdd"zp'<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <M-j>  @='"zx"zp`[V`]'<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <M-k>  @='k"zdd"zpk'<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <M-k>  @='"zxk"zP`[V`]'<CR>
```

The point of `@='...'` is to allow these macros to be given *counts*, so that I can f.i. mark a few lines, then press <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Alt-j</kbd> and move the entire block 3 lines down.  The <kbd>Alt-c</kbd> combinations copies lines.

"But these don't preserve cursor position".  Yes: adding that part would leave you with nothing to do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both Tim Pope's [unimpaired plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590) and my own [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140) offer normal and visual mode mappings for this (and many more); you may want to take a look at the implementations, or use one of the plugins for a robust solution.

The reason that neither offers insert mode mappings is that this undermines the very power of Vim; its modality. Shuffling lines around is not inserting, it's editing, so you should (briefly) leave insert mode for that. Create an environment that makes this comfortable and quick; many people remap the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key. Don't work against the powerful Vim modes!

Comment: I also remapped `<Esc>` to `jj` and `kk` which is convenient, but I like my Vim to be intermediate between a modern editor and a modal editor. For this I use all the standards `<C-a>` for select all, `<C-c>` for yanking and `<C-v>` for pasting. This does not stop me for using registers when I want to do more complex things.